# List displaying object states

Tags: c#, list, iteration

When I print my List (inventory) it prints the same values multiple times instead of iterating properly:

```
List<Coffee> inventory = new List<Coffee>();

        Console.Write("Enter q to quit or the whole data as a comma delimited string using the following format Name,D,C,D:minQ or R:roast ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] values = s.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // Loop
        while (!s.ToLower().Equals("q"))
        {
            string name = values[0];
            string demand = (values[1]);
            string cost = (values[2]);
            string min = values[3];


            float D = CheckDemand(demand);
            float C = CheckCost(cost);
            float M = CheckMin(min);

            Decaf decafCoffee = new Decaf(name, D, C, M);
                   inventory.Add(decafCoffee);

            Console.Write("\nEnter q to quit or the whole data as a comma delimited string using the following format Name,D,C,D:minQ or R:roast: ");
            s = Console.ReadLine();
        }   // End loop

        // Display values
        Console.WriteLine("\nName \t   C ($)      Demand \t  Detail   Q(lbs.)     TAC ($)      T(weeks) ");
        for (int j = 0; j < inventory.Count; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", inventory[j].toString());
        }
```

Any ideas why this is? Do I need to implement a certain interface?

Comment: Give us some sample input and what is the output you get? Have you tried debugging the program to see what is in your list after getting out of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your line with `string[]` values  inside the while-loop:

```
 string s = Console.ReadLine();
 // Loop
 while (!s.ToLower().Equals("q"))
 {
      string[] values = s.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      ...
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `ToString()` on an object you will typically just get the fully qualified name of the type.  It depends what you want to see printed, but you should try displaying the members of the Coffee class.  For example:

```
foreach(Coffee c in inventory)
{
   Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
}
```

I went ahead and switch you from a `for` loop to a `foreach`.

Comment: IMO it would be best to override the `ToString` method on the `Coffee` class so that you can use the method effectively anywhere.

Comment: I think that Coffee.ToString() (which is not in the example) will show the inner values. So then inventory[j].toString() would be correct. Furthermore does it not really matter if he uses for or foreach.

Comment: @MartinMulder, you can think that but you'd be wrong.  You can also use `for` instead of `foreach` if you don't care about how clean your code is.  `foreach` was invented for exactly this situation and there is no reason not to use it.

Comment: And if you still don't believe you me give the documentation for ToString a read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx

Comment: @Abe: True... foreach would be better in this case, but it simply is not an answser to his question. And I doubt that your suggestion to display "c.Name" is either, because it would print multiple times the same name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
string[] values = s.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

inside your while loop.